# Knockoutjs: Split a string into an array of string

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm a newbie in knockout so please forgive my ignorance.

This is my knockout.js file:

```
self.names = ko.observable(); // john, mary, jimmy
var arrNames= new Array();
arrNames = self.names().toString().split(",");
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined

I've tried:

```
self.names().split(",");
self.names.split(",");
```

But nothing works. Please help.

On related note: How can I split the string into an array based on a comma or linebreak?

Comment: can you share the output of `console.log(typeof self.names)`?

Comment: it prints "function"

Comment: what is the output of console.log(typeof self.names())?

Comment: try  `self.names = ko.observable('');`

Comment: @tmg that worked! thanks so much. can you please tell me why did it work?

Comment: cause `typeof self.names()` was `undefined`

Answer (score 2):

You can use computed in order to get recalculable result:

```
self.names = ko.observable(); // john, mary, jimmy
self.arrNames = ko.computed(function() { return self.names() && self.names().split(",") || []; });
```

Sample usage:

```
var a = self.arrNames() // a = []
self.names("john,mary,jimmy");
var b = self.arrNames() // b = ["john", "mary", "jimmy"]
```

Answer (score 2):

becasue if you evaluated `self.names() == undefined` and undefined type do not have toString property ;)

try instead:

```
self.names = ko.observable("");
```

or

```
(self.names()||'').split(",");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here your observable is not properly updated with your string values.

Look at the below code.

```
    self.names = ko.observable(); 
    self.names('john, mary, jimmy');
    var arrNames= new Array();
    arrNames = self.names().toString().split(",");
    console.log(arrNames);
```

When you want to update self.name it should be updated like this self.names("new strings, old strings'), not like self.names = "new, old".

Hope this helps you.